# Laravel функция внутри функции

Tags: php, laravel

В общем есть класс и в нем три функции, в них очень много одинакового кода, можно ли как то вынести эти одинаковые куски в отдельную сущность, и затем использовать ее из тех функций? Подскажите плиз, не могу найти четкого ответа

Пример:

```
public function useOne($id) {
  $x = $id*2;
  $cc = $x*10;
}
public function useTwo($id) {
  $x = $id*5;
$cc = $x*10;
}
```

А хотелось бы что-то типа:

```
    public function useOne($id) {
        $cc = new GetCC($id, 2);
    }
    public function useTwo($id) {
        $cc = new GetCC($id, 5);
    }
```

Comment: приведите код вашего класса

Comment: @madfan41k обновил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    namespace App;      
    Class GetCC{
      public $id;
      public $coef;
      function __construct($id,$coef){
        return ($id*$coef)*10;
      }
     }
```

Comment: А куда мне закинуть этот класс, чтобы laravel его мог подтянуть и использовать?

Comment: Создайте модель GetCC, простую не привязанную к таблице, и подключите ее  use app\GetCC

Comment: то есть просто <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class GetCC
{
    //
}

Comment: не надо подключать eloquent, у вас же класс не работает с базой данных