# Как использовать функцию внутри функции

Tags: laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V2;

class BaseController extends Controller
{

    public function check(){
            return "Это вернула функция check"
        }

    public function day(){
             $this->check();
            return "Это вернула функция day"
        }
}
```

При вызове функции `day()` я получаю результат `Это вернула функция day`

Хотя по идеи должно вернуться `Это вернула функция check` и остановиться выполнение программы  ?

Comment: `$this->check();`

Comment: В Вашем ответе функция не выполняется, но ошибок нет

Comment: Покажите весь больше кода из контроллера.

Comment: Не дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/857436 ?

Comment: А с чего должно выполнение `day()` остановиться? `$this->check();` просто вернуло строку, вернуло в своей функции, а не в вызываемой. В вызываемой если будет `return $this->check();` - остановится и выведет нужную строку.

Comment: Тогда не подскажите как к примеру в функции  check() вернуть строку и остановить выполнение программы дальше ?

Comment: Как вариант: заменить `$this->check();` на `$x = $this->check(); if(!empty($x)){ return $x; }`. Получится, что если `check()` хоть что-то вернул (не пустое), то оно и вернется, иначе вернется `Это вернула функция day`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V2;

class BaseController extends Controller
{

    public function check(){
            return "Это вернула функция check"
        }

    public function day(){
            return $this->check();
            //любой код ниже выполняться не будет
            return "Это вернула функция day"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка на уровне понимания работы php

Рассмотрим метод:

```
    public function day(){
       
        // вызов ниже отрабатывает, но он возвращает свой результат в никуда
        // вы не присваиваете результат работы метода какой либо переменной
        $this->check();
        
        // Если вы хотите вывести данные двух методов сделайте например так

        $result = $this->check();

        return $result . "Это вернула функция day"
    }
```